# How to avoid redeclaring tag libraries in included JSP files?

Tags: java, jsp, include, jstl

I made myself a template for all JSPs in my webapp that keeps things very simple:

```
<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>

<!-- Put unique content here -->

<%@ include file="footer.jsp" %>
```

I decided to move my navigation menu out of header.jsp into its own file as it is getting larger.  I put the code for the menu into menu.jsp.    Here is how the include looks inside of my **header.jsp:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My JSP</title>
</head>

    <body>

        <jsp:include page = "menu.jsp"/>

 ......
```

However, menu.jsp will not work unless I also put this line in it:

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

That is already in my header.jsp.  I would like to only to have to put it there.  However when I try using this sytax instead:

```
<%@ include file="menu.jsp" %>
```

I get an error message from WebLogic 11g stating that

```
<%@ include file="header.jsp" %> is self refrencing
```

How can I include menu.jsp in header.jsp without having to include the JSTL in menu.jsp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A JSP page included *dynamically* (`<jsp:include />`) must have a taglib declaration if it uses the taglib because it is compiled separately.

A JSP page included statically doesn't have the same restriction because it's compiled into the servlet itself.

What's the big deal about declaring a taglib in a JSP in which it's used? That makes it a standalone "chunk" of functionality, dynamically includable anywhere, self-documenting, without worrying about the page it's being included in: this is the goal of breaking up functionality.

Comment: I didn't look at it that way.  I was in the mindset of aiming to repeat as little as possible.  I was also wondering if my solution was doing it "the wrong way"

Comment: @Steve It's Java, you're doomed to repetition ;) Using dynamic includes also allows really simple templating without the complexity of Tiles/SiteMesh/etc. Less power, but often more than enough.

Comment: LOL.  I'm learning Spring.  I have been very impressed with AOP and the other ways "new stuff" ( for me ) is reducing a lot of code.

Comment: @Steve AOP is a fantastic tool, used wisely. Things like Spring's TX management is perfect for AOP. AOP is frighteningly easy to abuse... but fun.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead directive `<%@ include file="page" %>` which includes source code of page, try standard action `<jsp:include page="page"/>` or JSTL `<c:import url="page"/>` which includes only dynamic response of page, not its code.